# How to use query parameter like strong parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters

How can i use query parameter as a strong parameter. 
This is my POST /tag method called by frontend to search posts.

```
def tag
  if params[:category] == 'Shop'
     render json: ShopPostPopulator.new(params[:search]).run
  else
     render json: Part.search(params[:search])
  end
end
```

If i want to use strong parameter instead of 'params[:search]', how should  I do it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'using `query` parameter like strong parameter'?

Comment: I am getting a search param from url... and i am sending this param value to a class method but i am asked to use strong parameter instead of passind directly param[:search]. What should i do?

Comment: Using strong params in this case doesn't seem to make any sense, so first of all, I would ask whoever asked you to do it why.

Answer (score 5):

[`ActionController::Parameters`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) is really just a hash like object and "strong parameters" is really just the equivalent of using `Hash#slice` to only allow a whitelist of attributes through. Which protects against mass assignment attacks. Beginners and often experienced Rails devs. seem to think that it magically filters and cleans the parameters. It doesn't - it just prevents you from getting a mass injection attack out of ignorance, stupidy or laziness.

Whitelisting is only needed if you are assigning a hash of parameters to a model:

```
User.update(
  params.permit(:email, :password)
)
```

In this case it prevents a malicious user from for example passing `role=superadmin` or `id=1` (as the first user is often the admin). If you are just assigning a single attribute from the params hash you don't need to use strong attributes. The major difference introduced back in 2012 is that whitelisting became manditory as an error is raised if you pass a ActionController::Parameters object without the `@permitted = true` attribute to `.new`, `.update`, `.create` and the other methods that spawn or update records.

If you want to though you can use `ActionController::Parameters#permit` to ensure that the parameter is a simple scalar type (not a hash or array):

```
params.permit(:search).fetch(:search, nil)
```

If `search` is an optional parameter with nested keys you can whitelist it like so:

```
params.fetch(:search, {}).permit(:foo, :bar)
```

You can also make the parameter required so that a ActionController::ParameterMissing exception is raised if its missing:

```
params.require(:search).permit(:foo, :bar)
```

Which is what you do 99% of the time in Rails since it bails early if we can't do anything meaning with the request.